# Elasticsearch Nest dynamic aggregation

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Im trying to run aggregation query in c# (using nest 5) but
I dont know how many aggregations I get as input and what are the aggregation type.

For example one query is:
{"aggs":{"type_count":{"terms":{"field":"type"}}}}

And other query will be:
{"aggs":{"type_count":{"terms":{"field":"type"}},"salary_count":
{"field":"salary"}}}

And other query may not contain aggregation at all.

How can I write this code dynamic in c#?

This is what I tried (I have case for selected aggregation types.
The problem is that this code support only one aggregation.

```
SearchDescriptor<object> SearchAgg = new SearchDescriptor<object>();
for (i=0;i < aggList.length;i++)
{
    SearchAgg.Aggregations(a => a.terms (aggList[i]), t=> t.Field(aggList[i]));
}
```

Edit:

I successed to add multiple aggregations using this code:

```
AggregationContainerDescriptor<SearchRequest> agg = new
AggregationContainerDescriptor<SearchRequest>();

agg.Terms("bucket", tm=> tm.Field("field"));
agg &= new AggregationContainerDescriptor<SearchRequest>().Terms("bucket2", tm=> tm.Field("field2"));
```

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the documentation on writing aggregations: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/writing-aggregations.html

Answer (score 7):

Generally speaking, method calls using the Fluent lambda expression syntax within NEST perform assignment as opposed to being additive, meaning that successive calls of the same method will overwrite what is assigned. In your example here

```
SearchDescriptor<object> SearchAgg = new SearchDescriptor<object>();
for (i=0;i < aggList.length;i++)
{
    SearchAgg.Aggregations(a => a.terms (aggList[i]), t=> t.Field(aggList[i]));
}
```

only the last  call to `SearchAgg.Aggregations(...)` will assign.

The [writing aggregations documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/writing-aggregations.html) has examples of issuing multiple aggregations. Given the following POCOs

```
public class Project
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastActivity { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Tags { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Branches { get; set; }
    public IList<CommitActivity> Commits { get; set; }
}

public class CommitActivity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public long SizeInBytes { get; set; }
}
```

where `CommitActivity` is mapped as a `nested` type, issuing two terms aggregation with a nested aggregation on commits to aggregate stats about commits for each project

#### Using fluent lambda expression syntax

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<Project>(s => s
    .Aggregations(aggs => aggs
        .Terms("project_tags", t => t.Field(p => p.Tags))
        .Terms("project_branches", t => t.Field(p => p.Branches))
        .Nested("commits", n => n
            .Path(p => p.Commits)
            .Aggregations(aa => aa
                .Stats("commit_size_stats", m => m.Field(p => p.Commits.First().SizeInBytes))
            )
        )
    )
);
```

#### Object Initializer syntax

```
var searchRequest = new SearchRequest<Project>
{
    Aggregations = new AggregationDictionary
    {
        { "project_tags", new TermsAggregation("project_tags") { Field = Nest.Infer.Field<Project>(p => p.Tags) } },
        { "project_branches", new TermsAggregation("project_branches") { Field = Nest.Infer.Field<Project>(p => p.Branches) } },
        { "commits", new NestedAggregation("commits") 
            {
                Path = Nest.Infer.Field<Project>(p => p.Commits),
                Aggregations = new AggregationDictionary
                {
                    { "commit_size_stats", new StatsAggregation("commit_size_stats", Nest.Infer.Field<Project>(p => p.Commits.First().SizeInBytes)) },
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

var searchResponse = client.Search<Project>(searchRequest);
```

Since ultimately aggregations on a search request is just a dictionary of aggregation name and the type of aggregation, using this syntax can grow big very quickly. for this reason, NEST overloads the logical `&&` operator and implements implicit conversions to allow combining aggregations in a more terse fashion

#### Terse Object Initializer syntax

```
var searchRequest = new SearchRequest<Project>
{
    Aggregations = 
        new TermsAggregation("project_tags") { Field = Nest.Infer.Field<Project>(p => p.Tags) } &&
        new TermsAggregation("project_branches") { Field = Nest.Infer.Field<Project>(p => p.Branches) } &&
        new NestedAggregation("commits") 
        {
            Path = Nest.Infer.Field<Project>(p => p.Commits),
            Aggregations = 
                new StatsAggregation("commit_size_stats", Nest.Infer.Field<Project>(p => p.Commits.First().SizeInBytes))
        }
};

var searchResponse = client.Search<Project>(searchRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its a few years since this question was asked, but I had the same issue.

Using NEST 7.17, I wanted to dynamically create multi-layer aggregation queries based on user choices. The Fluent style queries are great for fixed queries, but I was struggling to dynamically add multiple agg levels this way. I ended up creating the query bit-by-bit, an example is shown below.

This **is** a lot more verbose than the Fluent style; but I ending up wrapping the code here in methods to add each layer of bucket-aggregation, and value-aggregation, allowing me to dynamically create complex multi layer queries at will.

One thing that initially tripped me, was that the *AggregationDictionary()* constructor makes a copy of all details, so ensure you call these last, once the other details have been fully assembled.

```
/*
 Index for sample will be:
    country - keyword
    region - keyword
    price - float
*/        

// Level 1 - Break out 'Country' into buckets
var aggDictL1 = new Dictionary<string, IAggregationContainer>();
var terms = new TermsAggregation("country_level");
terms.Size = 100;
terms.Field = new Field("country.keyword");
aggDictL1["country_level"] = new AggregationContainer { Terms = terms };

// Total cost for each country
aggDictL1["total_cost"] = new AggregationContainer 
{
    Sum = new SumAggregation("total_cost", new Field("price"))
};


// Level 2 - Break out 'Region' within each country
var aggDictL2 = new Dictionary<string, IAggregationContainer>();
var terms2 = new TermsAggregation("region_level");
terms2.Size = 100;
terms2.Field = new Field("region.keyword");
aggDictL2["region_level"] = new AggregationContainer { Terms = terms2 };

// Total cost for each bucket within layer above ('Country' in this case)
aggDictL2["country_cost"] = new AggregationContainer
{
    Sum = new SumAggregation("country_cost", new Field("price"))
};


// Level 3 - Total cost for each region
var aggDictL3 = new Dictionary<string, IAggregationContainer>();

// Total cost for each bucket within layer above ('Region' in this case)
aggDictL3["region_cost"] = new AggregationContainer
{
    Sum = new SumAggregation("region_cost", new Field("price"))
};

// Assemble layers - do this last as AggregationDictionary() will copy details
aggDictL2["region_level"].Aggregations = new AggregationDictionary(aggDictL3);
aggDictL1["country_level"].Aggregations = new AggregationDictionary(aggDictL2);


// Assemble request
var sd = new SearchRequest<SpotRecord>(Indices.Index(indexName));
sd.Size = 0;
sd.Query = <your filter here...>
sd.Aggregations = new AggregationDictionary(aggDictL1);

// Run it
var ret = _client.Search<SpotRecord>(sd);
```